# Storing words in a text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, nlp

I am building an application for learning languages, with Rails and Postgresql.

Texts get uploaded. The texts will be of varying length, but let’s assume they’ll be 100-3000 words long.

On upload, each text position gets transformed into a “token”, representing information about the word at that position (base word, noun/verb/adjective/etc., grammar tags, definition_id).

On click of a word in the text, I need to find (and show) all other texts in the database that have words with the same attributes (base_word, part of speech, tags) as the clicked word.

The easiest and most relational way to do this is a join table `TextWord`, between the table `Text` and `Word`. Each `text_word` would represent a position in the text, and would contain the `text_id`, `word_id`, `grammar_tags`, `start_index`, and `end_index`.

However, if a text has between 100-3000 words, this would mean 100-3000 entries for each text object.

Is that crazy? Expensive? What problems could this lead to?

Is there a better way?

I can’t use Postgres full text search because, for example, if I click “left” in “I left Nashville”, I don’t want “take a left at the light” to show up. I want only “left” as a verb, as well as other forms of “leave” as a verb. Furthermore, I might want only “left” with a specific definition_id (ex. “Left” used as “The political party”, not “the opposite of right”).

The other option I can think of is to store a JSON on the text object, with the tokens as a big **hash of hashes**, or array of hashes (either way). Does Postgresql have a way to search through that kind of nested data structure?

A third option is to have the same JSON as option 2 (to store all the positions in a text), and a 2nd json on each word object / definition object / grammar object (to store all the positions across all texts where that object appears). However, this seems like it might take up more storage than a join table, and I’m not sure if it would bring any tangible benefit.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? Use PostgreSQL full text search.

Comment: Because if I click “left” in “I left Nashville”, I don’t want “take a left at the light” to come up (left => noun). They need to be linked at the base word / part of speech level. I want only the verb “leave” (“left”, but also “leaves”, “leave”). Also, I might eventually want only the ones tagged a specific definition_id.

Comment: In other words (no pun intended), I need to search by specific attributes attached to each position, not just a straight text match. I wish it were that simple. But... Tower of Babel, yo.

Comment: However: Would postgres full text search let me search through a hash as if it were text...? To find specific attributes inside the hash?

Comment: You compute a `tsvector` from the text (which is probably the PostgreSQL equivalent of the hash you envision), and use the `@@` operator to search for a `tsquery`. But if you need to match based on a grammatical analysis of the text (i.e., disambiguate different `left`), that cannot be done with PostgreSQl full text search. The cool thing about PostgreSQL's full text search (or better, one of the cool things) is that it can be quite fast with a GIN index.

Comment: Maybe you could try asking here https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution would be to have a database with several indexes: one for the base word, one for the part-of-speech, and one for every other feature you're interested in.

When you click on *left*, you identify it's a form of "leave", and a "verb" in the "past tense". Now you go to your indexes, and get all token position for "leave", "verb", and "past tense". You take the intersection of all the index positions, and you are left with the token positions of the forms you're after.

If you want to save space, have a look at [Managing Gigabytes](https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/ammoffat/mg/), which is an excellent book on the topic. I have in the past used that to fully index text corpora with millions of words (which was quite a lot 20 years ago...)

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. When you say “manage several indexes”, is that essentially a join table between the Text and the word features?

Comment: As far as I understand, a foreign key in Postgresql is an index and an integer. So unless I’m misunderstanding, this is the TextWord table that I reference in my post, correct? Is there any difference?

Comment: Probably. I didn't use Postgres, but coded my own index files (following the MG book)